# Exception calling "ExecuteNonQuery" with "0" argument(s): "Failed to convert parameter value from a Object[] to a IEnumerable 1."

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I am attempting to take the results from a stored procedure on one server and insert it via a stored procedure on another server passing in the results as a data table.  When I do this, I get this error:

> Exception calling "ExecuteNonQuery" with "0" argument(s): "Failed to convert parameter value from a Object[] to a IEnumerable 1."

I think it's choking on trying to convert the data table into something it can pass to the stored procedure, but I am unsure on what the correct way to do this is and couldn't find an answer online.

PowerShell:

```
function Get-IndexBlitz
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
        param 
        (
            [string] $server
        )


    Write-Host "    Get Index Blitz"


    $dt = GetBlitzResults $server


    $sqlConnection = new-object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
    $sqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Server=server_name; Database=Monitor_Reporting;Trusted_Connection=True;"
    $sqlConnection.Open()


    $sql = '[CentMang].[InsertIndexBlitzResults]'
    $sqlCommand = new-object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
    $sqlCommand.Connection = $sqlConnection
    $sqlCommand.CommandText = $sql
    $sqlCommand.CommandType = [System.Data.CommandType]::StoredProcedure
    $sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@server", [System.Data.SqlDbType]::VarChar).value = $server
    $sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@results", [System.Data.SqlDbType]::Structured).value = $dt


    $sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()

    $sqlConnection.Close()
}


function GetBlitzResults
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
        param 
        (
            [string] $server
        )

    Write-Host "        Get Results"
    $sqlConnection = new-object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
    $sqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Server='$server'; Database=DBAdmin;Trusted_Connection=True;"
    $sqlConnection.Open()


    $sql = '[DBAdmin].[ozar].[sp_BlitzIndex]'
    $sqlCommand = new-object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
    $sqlCommand.Connection = $sqlConnection
    $sqlCommand.CommandText = $sql
    $sqlCommand.CommandType = [System.Data.CommandType]::StoredProcedure
    $sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@Mode", [System.Data.SqlDbType]::TinyInt).value = 0
    $sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@GetAllDatabases", [System.Data.SqlDbType]::Bit).value = 1
    $sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@BringThePain", [System.Data.SqlDbType]::Bit).value = 1
    $sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@ThresholdMB", [System.Data.SqlDbType]::Int).value = 250


    $Datatable = New-Object System.Data.DataTable
    $DataReader = $sqlCommand.ExecuteReader()
    $Datatable.Load($DataReader)

    $sqlConnection.Close()

    return $Datatable
}
```

Stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [CentMang].[InsertIndexBlitzResults]
    @server varchar(512),
    @results [CentMang].[BlitzIndexResults] readonly
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
INSERT INTO [Monitor_Reporting].[CentMang].[IndexBlitzResults]
(
    [DateGathered]
    ,[ServerName]
    ,[Priority]
    ,[Finding]
    ,[DatabaseName]
    ,[Details]
    ,[Definition]
    ,[SecretColumns]
    ,[Usage]
    ,[Size]
    ,[MoreInfo]
    ,[URL]
)
select
    getutcdate(),
    @server as [server],
    r.[priority],
    r.finding,
    r.databasename,
    r.details,
    r.[definition],
    r.secretcolumns,
    r.usage,
    r.size,
    r.moreinfo,
    r.[url]
from @results r
END
GO
```

User defined table type:

```
CREATE TYPE [CentMang].[BlitzIndexResults] AS TABLE(
    [priority] [int] NULL,
    [finding] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [databasename] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [details] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [definition] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [secretcolumns] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [usage] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [size] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [moreinfo] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [url] [nvarchar](max) NULL
)
```

Comment: Instead of `return $Datatable`, try `return ,$Datatable`.

Comment: @DanGuzman huh, that worked.  I then discovered i was missing a column in by table type, but that worked.  Thank you!